# Binding the property to a control defined inside a listboxitem template

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have a class called ledgerObject :

```
public class LedgerObject
{
    public ChargeLine ChargeLine{ get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand Click_hyperbnCommand{ get; private set; }

    public LedgerObject()
    {
        this.Click_hyperbnCommand = new DelegateCommand(click_btn);
    }

    private void click_btn(object args)
    {
    }
}
```

The chargeLine which is the property of this class is itself a class and has some properties in it.

So I am binding the datacontext of a listbox to an array of LedgerObject, and I want to bind the textblock control defined inside a listboxitem template to the property of a ChargeLine. Any idea or suggestion will help.

I have tried this but not working:

```
<TextBlock Margin="4 0 4 0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=ChargeLine.SimCode}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Red" />
```

Comment: The code you tried is missing.

Comment: Hmm. My answer is essentially what you've already tried. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I can't see any result in my listbox..
I debuged it the datacontext has the data but doesn't display in listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `ItemsSource`-Property of the ListBox instead of the `DataContext`.

// edit

The reasons are explained [here](http://anyedotnet.blogspot.com/2008/11/datacontext-vs-itemssource.html) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9bfdb32c-a4ce-46ad-b977-e12d51e815e2) in more detail.

Comment: Ah! The real problem was hidden in the text of his question! Well played! +1!

Comment: Hi gammelgul, it worked but can you just explain why it was not working with the data context.